# Angular lazy loading modules possible with Maven

Tags: java, node.js, angular, maven, angular8

I am using maven multi-module project to create war file to integrate angular and spring-boot application. Is it possible to do lazy loading feature module chunks using maven? This is my front end pom.xml:

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ParentDashboard</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>Frontend</artifactId>

  <name>Frontend</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v10.16.3</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>6.9.0</npmVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/web/</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install --production</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                     <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prod</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I could see chunks created in visual studio code but with this maven configuration, I could not see chunks in eclipse console. Could some one help?

Answer (score 0):

Seems i've resolved it using below configuration in package.json.

```
"build": "ng build --prod --aot --base-href=\"./\"".
```

Now I could see individual module chunk created in eclipse console and see chunk in devTools network console.